# SQL server replication - Does not ask for the snapshot folder

Tags: sql-server, replication

SQL SERVER 2008

When I created a publisher for the first time, it asked for the snapshot folder path. I deleted that replication and tried to recreate the publisher. This time it doesn't even ask for the path for snapshot folder.

Why is that? and how can I force this to ask for a snapshot path.

If I change the path to one replication (that I am going to create, will it change for all the replications that is running on the sql instance?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server asks for a root snapshot folder path when you [Configured Publishing and Distribution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151192.aspx).

After configuring publishing and distribution, all subsequent publications created will use that snapshot folder but will have their own sub-folder within that folder.

If you wish to have your snapshot files for a particular publication be put into a different root snapshot folder, specify this by passing in the path to the **@alt_snapshot_folder** parameter of [sp_addpublication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188738.aspx) or [sp_addmergepublication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176103.aspx) when you create the publication.  Alternatively, this can be done from the *Publication Properties* dialog after you have created your publication and before generating a snapshot on the *Snapshot* page, *Location of snapshot files* section, ***Put files in the following folder***.

[image]

If you have anymore questions, please let me know.

I hope this helps.